# Transfer ERC20 tokens

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transferfrom

I try to implement functionality of burning ERC20 token.Transaction is failed during calling "transferFrom" function. Who knows what's the problem? I guess there is an error in allowance.

```
function burnERC20(uint256 _amount, address _sender, address _tokenAddress) internal returns(bool){
       IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
       uint8 tokenDecimals = tokenContract.decimals();
       tokenContract.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
       require(tokenContract.balanceOf(_sender) >= _amount * 10^tokenDecimals, 'you do not have enough funds');
       bool sent = tokenContract.transferFrom(_sender, address(0), _amount);
       return sent;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to transfer tokens:

1. Direct transfer with `transfer`. The owner (party A) issues a transaction to transfer tokens from himself to some other address (party B). So tokens are transferred from A to B.
2. Indirect transfer with `approve` and `transferFrom`. This is what you are trying to use. But this requires both of the parties to do something: A has to call `approve` and give B's address as the address to be allowed to withdraw tokens. After that, B calls `transferFrom` which utilizes the allowance.

But, since you are *burning* tokens by sending them to the zero address 0x0, you have to use the first method, since the receiver (0x0) can't call approve. So you have to use direct transfer: the owner of the tokens has to call the token contract's burn function (which sends the tokens to 0x0).

The `allowance` function you are using is simply a `view` function which doesn't perform any state changes - it simply gives you the current allowance status.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I tried to pass TUSD 0xd92e713d051c37ebb2561803a3b5fbabc4962431 as ERC20 token and transfer it to zero address but it still fails. 
Here is code 
function transferERC20Token(address _tokenAddress, uint256 _amount)external {
        IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
         uint8 tokenDecimals = tokenContract.decimals();
         require(tokenContract.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount * 10^tokenDecimals, 'you do not have enougth funds');
         tokenContract.transfer(address(0), _amount * 10**tokenDecimals);
     }